# How to print the pattern? (interview question)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, pattern-matching

Write a function to print the following pattern.
Given n as the parameter of the function which denotes the number of lines of the output.

**Example:**

---

**Input:** 2

**Output:**

0

1 4

---

**Input:** 3

**Output:**

0

1 4

5 8 12

---

**Input** - 5

**Output** -

0

1 4

5 8 12

13 16 20 25

26 29 33 38 44

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Stef Author wants a function in python to print the pattern consists of n lines.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern started from 0, We need to print n lines.

**Observation-1:**

If the line number is 1, then print 0.

else the first value of the line is the **last value(of the previous line) + 1**.

**Observation-2:**

On a particular line, the pattern is as follows:

*previous-value + 3, previous-value + 4, previous-value + 5......*

```
def pattern(n):
    curr = 0 
    for row in range(n):
        print(curr,end = ' ')
        add = 3
        for index in range(row):
            curr = curr + add
            add  = add + 1
            print(curr,end = ' ')
        curr = curr + 1
        print()

pattern(5)
```

Comment: Just writing the code isn't a good answer, kindly add an explanation as well

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I have added some explanations, Could you check it, please?